# High performance, private, redundant blockchain without miners

Tags: blockchain

I am looking for a blockchain platform where I have the following properties:

- number of transactions are > 500 000 / day
- data volume is high so that we cannot store all of the data on all nodes
- replication factor should be tuneable for each transaction (3-10)
- data is stored in each transaction (not only the hash of the data)
- it can host many different blockchains (like database tables)
- these blockchains can be replicated to different clusters (multiple datacenter support)
- search is a first class citizen in this product (the content is indexed)
- data replication can be tuned so that 3rd parties get only the transactions and the hash of data or full access (including the data)

Not sure if such a system exists today. I am aware of the following projects that might be able to deliver these properties with modifications:

- https://iota.org/
- https://hashgraph.com/

I would appreciate if somebody would point me to the right direction.